# An Array of ALLEGRO_BITMAP type objects

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, allegro

So I'm making a game using Allegro and I was trying to create an array of ALLEGRO_BITMAP type objects which would represent the board, so that I could load my images files all at once in the beginning of the game and not have to load them every time I want to redraw them. I attempted to do that like so:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP files[10];
```

which gets the following compilation error: 'Field has incomplete type ALLEGRO_BITMAP'

I also tried:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* files = new ALLEGRO_BITMAP[10];
```

which gets the compilation error: 'Allocation of incomplete type ALLEGRO_BITMAP'

I have a feeling this has something to do with the compiler not knowing the size of an ALLEGRO_BITMAP type and therefore not knowing how to allocate memory for an array of this type (but can someone please correct me if I'm wrong). I was wondering if someone knew a way around this? Or another way to achieve my goal of storing the ALLEGRO_BITMAP objects upfront rather then loading the image files when I want to redraw a tile? I can obviously create 10 different variables and store the files in them but this is gross. I have tried to use vectors as well, but those did not work either.

Comment: It seems that you are missing some include directive. The compiler does't know about ALLEGRO_BITMAP type. Check your inclusion.

Comment: @Heisenbug My inclusion is fine and adding this line: 'ALLEGRO_BITMAP * b;' compiles fine. It is only when I try to allocate an array.

Comment: I guess you have just forward declared it. So you can use pointer but can't allocate because you actually don't know the size of the struct.

Comment: @Heisenbug my thoughts exactly, but I was hoping on some sort of confirmation/solution. Maybe someone else can confirm this theory?

Comment: The solution is removing the forward declaration, if any and include the header file with the definition. Sorry but I don't know which file is, I don't know allegro at all. Try to google for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of Allegro 5 data types are opaque.

You need to create an array of pointers:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *files[10];
files[0] = al_create_bitmap(640, 480);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Quick question though just for my general knowledge: What does opaque mean?

Comment: Wait never mind my mistake. so al_create_bitmap returns a pointer to an ALLEGRO_BITMAP object, not the object itself? Sorry I didn't realize that. Thanks!

Comment: @user1413793, an opaque data structure is one that does not reveal its "internals". This is all that is in the public header file: `typedef struct ALLEGRO_BITMAP ALLEGRO_BITMAP`. So instead of `bmp->w`, you use `al_get_bitmap_width(bmp)`. The purpose of this is it exposes less of the implementation details to user code, making it easier to change things in the future. If you really want access to the bitmap structure in Allegro 5, you need to include a separate private header file, but with the understanding that it's not guaranteed to be future compatible.